# SQL 2012 in Hyper-V. Why are my queries slow until I drop and create any spatial index?

Tags: performance, hyper-v, sql, sql-server-2012, gis

I have a spatial application that queries several tables (layers) each time the user pans/zooms the map.  When I moved the SQL server into Hyper-V, I noticed that there was a several second delay when querying one of the tables.  I disabled this table from the queries and then another table became slow etc.

Strangely, by dropping and creating any spatial index of any table in the DB (even one I'm not querying), the performance magically becomes lightning fast until I reboot or create a new connection.

I tried using a pass-through disk but it didn't make any difference.  This "bug" does not occur on the same hardware when running native SQL server (not virtual).  I also tried Hyper-V on a different desktop PC and I also tried SQL 2014 Express but got the same problem.

Is there any other Hyper-V/SQL setting that I can try?  Is there any explanation as to why dropping and creating an index temporarily fixes the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems to be the cost of Virtualization in some scenarios. If you are running with dynamic memory which uses a memory balloon driver try configuring the VM to have a set amount of RAM. Watch teh memory utilization of both the host and guest. If you see that memory is increasingly getting consumed try disabling lock pages in memory. One thing that you can try is with all guests powered off and the host freshly booted, just boot the single guest running SQL. If the queries run as they should then the other guest machines are robbing that VM of the needed resources. This can happen when a server isn't sized properly and is quite common. A way around this is to add an additional array of disks and dedicate it to just that VM. Another way to cheat the system in a way is to use SSD caching for the database. A couple of other things to consider is if you shutdown the SQL service and use a tool like UltraDefrag and run a full optimization and defrag, then bring the service back up if the query performs any faster. You can get UltraDefrag which is opensource and free at http://ultradefrag.sf.net lastly Microsoft has a paper you might want to check your configurations with. Check out: http://www.slideshare.net/ManuelCastro8/high-performance-sql-server-workloads-on-hyper-v

One other thing to try is use ESXi instead of Hyper-V, or the latest Hyper-V 2012 R2.

Lastly, with the full version of SQL what exact version is being ran? What exact OS is being ran for the guest and host? Do you have the latest integration services installed?